# How to print Google AdSense code in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, adsense

I've developed WordPress theme, and plan to add a Google ads option, but I can't print the Google AdSense code. How can i print it?

```
$googleads_code = get_field('custom_ads');
echo '<div class="adbox">'.$googleads_code.'</div>';
```

This code can't print Google ads on my template. How can I do this?

Comment: Is it return nothing: ?  `echo get_field('custom_ads'); `

Comment: use the_field('custom_ads'); to print

Answer (score 0):

1) Close the div tag before the variable

2) Use the variable that has the code

```
$googleads_code = get_field('custom_ads');
echo '<div class="adbox">' . $googleads_code . '</div>';
```

Comment: Ohh. I'm sorry. I've closed it on my code. But Wrong written on top. Edited it.  sorry my poor english. :(